# How to solve the differential equation $y'' + y = e^{x^2}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Could any experts give some suggestions on how to solve the differential equation $y'' + y = e^{x^2}$?

This ODE stems from a physics problem I need to solve. It describes a rectangular substrate subjected to a perpendicular force.

Comment: "x2" is x square

Comment: Besides expressing a particular solution as a power series?

Comment: I try to get a particular solution but failed because of the x square

Comment: The general solution is $A\cos x+B\sin x+\int_0^x\sin(x-t)e^{t^2}\,dt$, but the integral will not admit a representation as an elementary function. Do you mind giving some more context about  where you found this exercise (course?). That might help us to give a better answer.

Comment: How about looking for solutions of the form $P(x)e^{x^2}$, where $P$ is a polynomial or power series? Would that help?

Comment: This equation derive from a physical problem i need to solve, it describes a rectangular substrate subjected to a normal direction force.Not a text book problem, really thanks !

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help. I had tried P(x)ex2 previously, it will never work.

Comment: Hi, Interms of Acos(x) solution what is t? Thanks for your help@mickep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mickep has said, the general solution is
$$A\cos x+B\sin x+\int_0^x\sin(x-t)e^{t^2}\,dt$$
($t$ is a variable of integration. It is simply an artifact of notation, not a real value upon which the function depends. Just like if you write $\sum_{i=1}^4 i$, this is just $1 + 2 + 3 + 4$, not some function of $i$.)

Since there is no nice form for the integration, we can expand by Taylor series about $0$. Fixing the value of $x$, if $f(t) = \sin(x-t)e^{t^2}$, the first few derivatives are

- $f(0) = \sin x$
- $f'(0) = -\cos x$
- $f''(0) = \sin x$
- $f'''(0) = -5\cos x$ (assuming I didn't make a mistake).

So $$f(t) = \sin x - t\cos x + \frac {t^2}2\sin x - \frac {5t^3}6\cos x +\ ...$$
and $$\int_0^x f(t)dt = x\sin x -\frac {x^2}2\cos x + \frac {x^3}6\sin x - \frac {5x^4}{24}\cos x +\ ...$$

And your general solution becomes
$$A\cos x+B\sin x+ x\sin x -\frac {x^2}2\cos x + \frac {x^3}6\sin x - \frac {5x^4}{24}\cos x +\ ...$$
Depending on your problem, you may need more terms before the remainder becomes negligible.

Comment: Really detail answer, Thanks a lot! I will write down your notes seriouly and study!!!